# How to repair Unity registry on Windows 10?

Tags: unity-game-engine, registry

I use `PlayerPrefs` to save some user data. I know that on Windows the data is actually saved in the registry under the `\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Unity\companyname` key.

It used to be like this:

```
Unity
  |--BugReporterV2
  |--UnityEditor
  |--companyname
      |--some other things that I don't remember, maybe the project name then some detailed values
  |--WebPlayer
```

I was intended to set all `PlayerPrefs` to default, so I deleted the whole key of `companyname` - stupidly without backup. Then in testing, I found that when calling

```
PlayerPrefs.SetString("testKey", "test");
```

it raised an exception

> PlayerPrefsException: Could not store preference value

How can I repair the structure of the registry?

Can someone show me how the registry saved data with `PlayerPrefs`  looks like under the "Unity" key with each keys and values please?  Maybe I could fixed it manually.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried reinstall unity, and the registry is fixed. The origininal clean registry looks like this:

```
Unity
 |--BugReporterV2
 |--UnityEditor
 |--WebPlayer
 |--companyname
     |--Project Name with Space
         |--unity.cloud_userid_xxxxxx // value is quite complicated
         |--UnityGraphicsQuality_xxxxxx // value is 5
```

The xxxxxx is something special for windows 10 that I'm not familiar with. Seems each key is followed by such a string that looks random to me. For anyone encountered similar issue, I think you can try creat the companyname and project name key. If the other keys are not created automatically after you run the project, then you could try reinstall unity.